# jenkins - list stages for each parallel branch

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-blueocean

I got code that list all branches and stages for my pipeline

```groovy
def List getBranchResults() {
    def visitor = new PipelineNodeGraphVisitor(currentBuild.rawBuild)
    echo "${visitor}"
    def branches = visitor.pipelineNodes.findAll{
        it.type == FlowNodeWrapper.NodeType.PARALLEL 
    }
    def stages = visitor.pipelineNodes.findAll{
        it.type == FlowNodeWrapper.NodeType.STAGE
    }
    echo "${stages}"
    def results = branches.collect{
        branch -> [ 
        id: branch.id, 
        displayName: branch.displayName, 
        result: "${branch.status.result}",]
    }
    echo "Branch results:\n" + results.join('\n')
}
def build_jobs = [:]
def build_results
build_jobs['1'] = {
    node('builder'){
        stage('A'){
            sh 'echo 1'
        }
        stage('B'){
           "error"
        }
    }
}
build_jobs['2'] = {
    node('builder'){
        sh 'echo 2'
    }
}
build_jobs['3'] = {
    node('builder'){
        stage('A'){
            sh 'echo 3'
        }
        stage('B'){
            
        }
    }
}
parallel build_jobs
getBranchResults( )
```

How I can connect between those two ?
I want to print for each branch it stages. Also I want to print the failed stage (if it exists) for each branch

For example:

```
Branch results:
[id:15, displayName:1, result:SUCCESS]
Stage results for 1:
[id=55,displayName=A,type=STAGE]
[id=25,displayName=B,type=STAGE] - FAILURE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can associate branches and child stages by querying [`FlowNode.allEnclosingIds`](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-api/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/graph/FlowNode.html#getAllEnclosingIds--)
for each node. If this list contains branch ID, we have a child stage.

I have implemented this in function `getStageResultsForBranch()` below. It appears to work with the sample code. If stages have nested sub stages, it will return these too, which may not be what you want.

**Sample code:**

```groovy
import io.jenkins.blueocean.rest.impl.pipeline.PipelineNodeGraphVisitor
import io.jenkins.blueocean.rest.impl.pipeline.FlowNodeWrapper

@NonCPS
def List getBranchResults() {

    def visitor = new PipelineNodeGraphVisitor(currentBuild.rawBuild)

    def branches = visitor.pipelineNodes.findAll{
        it.type == FlowNodeWrapper.NodeType.PARALLEL 
    }

    def results = branches.collect{ branch -> [ 
        id: branch.id, 
        displayName: branch.displayName, 
        result: "${branch.status.result}",
    ]}
    
    return results
}

@NonCPS
def List getStageResultsForBranch( String branchId ) {

    def visitor = new PipelineNodeGraphVisitor(currentBuild.rawBuild)

    def childStages = visitor.pipelineNodes.findAll{ stage ->
        stage.type == FlowNodeWrapper.NodeType.STAGE &&
        stage.node.allEnclosingIds.contains( branchId )
    }
    
    def results = childStages.collect{ stage -> [ 
        id: stage.id, 
        displayName: stage.displayName, 
        result: "${stage.status.result}",
    ]}
    
    return results
}

node {
    def build_jobs = [:]
    def build_results
    
    build_jobs['1'] = {
        stage('1.A'){
            sh 'echo 1'
        }
        stage('1.B'){
           error 'an error'
        }
    }
    build_jobs['2'] = {
        sh 'echo 2'
    }
    build_jobs['3'] = {
        stage('3.A'){
            sh 'echo 3'
        }
        stage('3.B'){
                        
        }
    }
    
    try {
        parallel build_jobs
    }
    finally {
        stage('Final') {
            for( branchRes in getBranchResults() ) {
                def stageResults = getStageResultsForBranch( branchRes.id )

                echo "BRANCH RESULT: $branchRes\n" +
                     "  STAGE RESULTS:\n  ${stageResults.join('\n  ')}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(I have removed the build job nodes for testing)

**Output:**

```text
BRANCH RESULT: [id:8, displayName:1, result:FAILURE]
  STAGE RESULTS:
  [id:12, displayName:1.A, result:SUCCESS]
  [id:29, displayName:1.B, result:FAILURE]

BRANCH RESULT: [id:9, displayName:2, result:SUCCESS]
  STAGE RESULTS:

BRANCH RESULT: [id:10, displayName:3, result:SUCCESS]
  STAGE RESULTS:
  [id:15, displayName:3.A, result:SUCCESS]
  [id:21, displayName:3.B, result:NOT_BUILT]
```