# How to get the agent that each stage is running on in a declarative jenkins pipeline using Groovy?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to get the agent name that each stage is running on. I can get this by making use of env.NODE_NAME, but then I'll have to write some code in each stage block to capture env.NODE_NAME from that stage.
I'm instead trying to capture the agents for all the stages at one place by getting the stage type FlowNodes via the PipelineNodeGraphVisitor, and getting the agent that these stage flowNodes are executing on. I read about making use of WorkSpaceAction to get the agent node, and I was able to get the agent via this.
Since my pipeline just has one agent defined at the pipeline level, I got that each stage is using the same agent. So, I tried using a different agent, say, 'test' for one stage and expected to get a different agent for that stage  via WorkSpaceAction, but I'm getting the same agent for it as the one defined at Pipeline level and not the 'test' agent.

Please help if anyone knows. I've been stuck on this for quite a long time now.

Here's the groovy code I used:

```
 WorkflowRun run = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(env.JOB_NAME)._getRuns()[0]
  FlowExecution exec = run.getExecution()
  PipelineNodeGraphVisitor visitor = new PipelineNodeGraphVisitor(run)
  def flowNodes = visitor.getPipelineNodes()

  for (Iterator iterator = flowNodes.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();)
  {
    def node = iterator.next()
    if (node.getType() == FlowNodeWrapper.NodeType.STAGE) //Get Stage Type flownodes
    {
      String stageName = node.getDisplayName()
      print "${stageName}"
     
      for (FlowNode enclosing : node.getNode().iterateEnclosingBlocks()) {
        WorkspaceAction ws = enclosing.getAction(WorkspaceAction.class)
        if (ws != null) {
           print "${ws.getNode()}"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi, have you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64418907/jenkins-list-stages-for-each-parallel-branch ?

Comment: Hi sumitani,I checked but it does not talk about agents for the flownodes either :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to unwrap the node from the FlowNodeWrapper, then get the execution and then use FlowGraphWalker to get all the contained nodes of a stage:

```
PipelineNodeGraphVisitor visitor = new PipelineNodeGraphVisitor(run)
def flowNodes = visitor.getPipelineNodes()

for (flowNode in flowNodes) {
  def node = flowNode.node
  def exec = node.execution
  def graphWalker = new FlowGraphWalker(exec)
  for (subNode in graphWalker) {
     if (subNode.allEnclosingIds.contains(node.id)) {
       def ws = subNode.getAction(WorkspaceAction.class)
       if (ws != null) {
         steps.echo "$subNode.displayName runs on ${ws.node}"
       }
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Munging the answers here, and in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43439093/determine-failed-stage-in-jenkins-declarative-pipeline), along with a fair amount of trial and error,  I came up with the following which has worked for me (I wasn't able to import PipelineNodeGraphVisitor or FlowNodeWrapper) :

```
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.flow.FlowExecution
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.actions.WorkspaceAction
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.visualization.table.FlowGraphTable

job = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName("my.pipeline.job")
if (job) {
    runs = job._getRuns()
    runs.each { run ->
        FlowExecution exec = run.getExecution()
        FlowGraphTable t = new FlowGraphTable(run.execution)
        t.build()

        for (def row in t.rows) {
            ws = row.node.getAction(WorkspaceAction)
            if (ws) {
                println ("${row.node.displayName}  :: ${row.node.url} :: ${ws.getNode()}\n")
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```